# Curved polyline from points using DXFEngine (python)

Tags: python, spline, dxf

I have a list of points (x,y) and want to create an output dxf file which contains a curved polyline between the points (spline approximation or similar).

Is this feasible using the dxfEngine python module?

Thanks in advance,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

I'm an idiot. Just use the spline function..!

```
from dxfwrite import DXFEngine as dxf
name = "spline.dxf"
drawing = dxf.drawing(name)

points = [(0,0), (1,1), (0,2), (1,3)]
spline = dxf.spline(points)

drawing.add(spline)

drawing.save()
```

Hope this helps other people who don't know how to rtfm.